# How can I let scripts span multiple lines in Jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Right now, I have this in a navigation view partial:

```
script.
    links = [
        {title: 'Dashboard', url: '/'},
        { title: 'Users', sublinks: [
                {title: 'Manage', url: '/users'}
            ] }
    ]
ul.nano-content
    - each link in links
        li
            a(href="#")= link.title
```

But Jade is complaining, I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

and it is pointing to `- each link in links`. This works when I put everything on one line, but it's ugly and is tough to read/maintain, how can I make it possible to span multiple lines like I have it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing two pieces of JavaScript - in-browser code you keep in between `<script>` tags, and backend JS. Contents of `script.` (`<script/>` tag) aren't bound to variables used in Jade template - so `links` in this line:

```
    - each link in links
```

is undefined - a direct cause of your error.

Solution depends on how you compile Jade template. Compilation is a process when as input you put both template itself and some data which will be bound to variables inside of template (i.e. `links` variable), and as an output you get HTML.

For instance, if you're serving it dynamically from Node.js backend, assuming you're using Express.js, you might want to define route similar to:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // .render() will take template named "index",
    // and a map with "links" property, and use it
    // to generate output HTML document.
    // Each key from the map will be bound at the template
    // level, so you'll be able to use it there.
    res.render('index', {links: [
        {title: 'Dashboard', url: '/'},
        { title: 'Users', sublinks: [
            {title: 'Manage', url: '/users'}
        ]}
    ]});
})
```

Comment: So... how can I create a multi line variable? Or is that possible?

Comment: See my updated answer. Basically, you can't use variables defined within `script.` tag defined in Jade template, in this template itself.